# Omniauth Facebook Avatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Trying to pull the avatar from Facebook but nothing seem to be loading. I think I accessing the Auth Hash correctly. Searching did not come up with much.

**User.rb**

```
def self.find_for_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)

# Get the identity and user if they exist
identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

# If a signed_in_resource is provided it always overrides the existing user
# to prevent the identity being locked with accidentally created accounts.
# Note that this may leave zombie accounts (with no associated identity) which
# can be cleaned up at a later date.
user = signed_in_resource ? signed_in_resource : identity.user

# Create the user if needed
if user.nil?

  # Get the existing user by email if the provider gives us a verified email.
  # If no verified email was provided we assign a temporary email and ask the
  # user to verify it on the next step via UsersController.finish_signup
  email_is_verified = auth.info.email && (auth.info.verified || auth.info.verified_email)
  email = auth.info.email if email_is_verified
  user = User.where(:email => email).first if email
  avatar = auth.info.image

  # Create the user if it's a new registration
  if user.nil?
    user = User.new(
      name: auth.extra.raw_info.name,
      username: auth.extra.raw_info.name || auth.uid,
      email: email ? email : "#{TEMP_EMAIL_PREFIX}-#{auth.uid}-#{auth.provider}.com",
      avatar: auth.info.image,
      password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    )
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.save!
  end
end
```

**Partial**

```
<%= link_to user_path(user) do %>
    <%= image_tag user.avatar.url || 'avatar.jpg', class: klass %>
<% end %>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: what's the type of the avatar column? it should be a string

Comment: It is a string. t.string

Comment: try user.avatar.url(:thumb)

Comment: Tired those and didnt work either.

Also went with:

`(auth.info.image + "?type=large").gsub("­http","htt­ps")`

Answer (score 0):

If `avatar` is a string, then how do you think this would work? `user.avatar.url` Of course it wouldn't. If `user.avatar` is a string, then it doesn't have a `url` method.

Simply use `<%= image_tag user.avatar %>`.